# Laravel 4: Why is my artisan command called 5 times in succession?

Tags: php, laravel

Today I bumped into something strange regarding an Artisan Command's lifecycle.

1. I added an artisan command named `cronjobs:MyCommand`.
2. Created the necessary files and classes.
3. Class `MyCommand` extends `BaseCommand`.

`BaseCommand` is something I put up to benchmark command line operations.
It consists of a constructor and destructor. The constructor keeps track of
the starting time of the operation, the destructor logs the current time minus
the starting time in a log table.

To my surprise I found out that the `__destruct()` function on my `BaseCommand` is
called 5 times in total every time I issue the `cronjobs:MyCommand` via artisan.

Is this normal behavior and if so how am I supposed to take care of logging instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further testing with Symfony 2's command class showed that this is a problem native to Symfony 2, not so much with laravel 4.

Using a constructor/destructor in an artisan command's class (or its parent) in any useful way seems impossible at this point in time.

Any input is still highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems still not fixed.. I had also creaed a basecommand with __destruct method which is gettigng executed multiple times.

I created a shutdown method in my basecommand and calling at the end of mycommand.